# Cancellation of outstanding async call?

Tags: ios, asynchronous

This is Parse-related but likely just as relevant in any call to cloud-based data. Firing off an async call, with a callback block, and testing via the Link Conditioner at 100% packet loss results in challenges. I have a template that manages it all, cancels the process, stops the internal block code from running should it ever decide to return,

BUT..

The actual call that keeps rolling, in this case, Parse's (for example) SaveInBackgroundWithBlock... simply seems to keep trying and trying, even when the app is rolling off onto other things.

I have not found any references to an ability to reach out and kill those calls, and thought to ask here for advice on how if possible, to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It is in general a tricky problem.

First, there is no way to *stop* any background task (well, none that I would ever dare using in iOS code of mine). You can only politely ask a background task to stop, for example by calling a "cancel" method.

So if *you* write a task that runs in the background and should be cancellable, it needs a "cancel" method, your code needs to check from time to time whether it is cancelled, and in that case stop doing work and tell others to cancel (NSOperationQueue has some support for this, that's IMO the only advantage it has compared to GCD).

If you have started an asynchronous operation that cannot be cancelled, then you are stuck. Sorry. The asynchronous operation needs to check itself, and it cannot be stopped from the outside if it has no feature built in for this. So the only thing you can do if cancelling is not possible, is to make sure that whatever that operation does, if it succeeds the results mustn't be used anymore, and if it fails it shouldn't show errors to the user.

Comment: Parse's async calls are essentially blackbox's so, i guess until they decide to open this part up, we are left with stranded bits of executing code. The only time this may impact me is during submission review when run against a Link Conditioner set to 100% packet loss, so hopefully it won't kill the acceptance.

edit: perhaps i spoke too soon. Looking into BFTask now, there may be a clue there.

Comment: All Parse's {Action}InBackgroundWithBlock methods return void, but the {Action}InBackground's return the BFTask. Not sure why exactly, as this kills the ability to cancel the task, but we can cancel the others. Too bad. I will ask directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need some descriptor or reference to the task you started. If Parse does not provide you any of these you may not be able to cancel the task.